# From Library of dmm classes want to select one and pass upwards with a common name

Tags: c#, class, interface

I have several namespaces representing various manufacturers DMM's
Racal_xxxxx
Agilent_Xxxxx
Fluke_xxxxx

As I understand it, I can write an interface that will enforce all the above to have the same functionality.

I can do what I want this way in Test_Station:

```
public Racal_4152A_DMM.main dmm = new Racal_4152A_DMM.main();
```

and I can use it in the next Class upwards, Test_Exec

Is there anyway to pass the dmm upwards without it being public?

And, do I really need to make it non-public.

The hierarchy is:

Test_Exec (needs to use Racal_4152A_DMM as dmm, but needs to be assigned as such in Test_Station)

Test_Station

Racal_4152A_DMM

All are separate namespaces

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are really only a matter of naming. They don't impose limits with respect to access rights. Therefore, if you want to hide classes, you either must wrap them in another class and make them private or place them in differents projects and make them internal.

I'll show you how you can wrap them in a class. Define a interface

```
public interface IMultimeter
{
    //TODO: declare members
}

public static class MulimeterFactory
{
    private class Racal_4152A : IMultimeter
    {
        //TODO: Implement interface
    }

    private class Agilent_XXX : IMultimeter
    {
        //TODO: Implement interface
    }

    public static IMultimeter Create_Racal_4152A()
    {
        return new Racal_4152A();
    }

    public static IMultimeter Create_Agilent_XXX()
    {
        return new Agilent_XXX();
    }
}
```

Now you can create DMMs like this

```
IMultimeter dmm = MulimeterFactory.Create_Racal_4152A();
```

The class `Racal_4152A` remains unvisible outside of `MulimeterFactory`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with separate class files?
That is:
Agilent_XXXX.cs
Fluke_xxxx.cs
Racal_XXXX.cs

So that the only thing that needs updating when a dmm is swapped out is the appropriate line in Test_Station.cs leaving Test_Exec.cs alone.

Comment: Yes, you can declare the factory as partial: `public static partial class MulimeterFactory`. This allows you to split it among different files within the same assembly and namespace. I.e. you can have several declarations `public static partial class MulimeterFactory`. The partial class is split physically but is still one single logical class.

Comment: Thanks! You have answered my question and improved my understanding! :)